# Troubleshooting my Bootstrap collapse accordeon

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

It seems I have some beginner problems...

I try to make a bootstrap collapse accordeon, with the effect, that the old and open element gets closed when a new is opened (basically like in the [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) ).

I have this Html Markup:

```
<form id="reserve_form" class="left resform_248" method="post" action="http://www.check24-7.in/demokiosk/direkt-buchen" name="reserve_form">
    <fieldset id="reservation_details">
        <legend>Buchungsdetails</legend>
        <ul>
            <li>Startdatum</li>
            <li>Enddatum</li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="personal_details">
        <legend>Pers&ouml;hnliche Daten</legend>
        <ul>
            <li>Vornamen</li>
            <li>Nachnamen</li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>`
```

And I used jQuery to add some more markup:

```
$("#reservation_details > ul")
    .attr("id", "reservation_details_content").addClass("collapse in");

$("#reservation_details > legend")
    .attr("data-toggle", "collapse")
    .attr("data-target", "#reservation_details_content")
    .attr("aria-expanded", "true")
    .attr("aria-controls", "reservation_details_content")
    .attr("data-parent", "#reserve_form");

$("#personal_details > ul")
    .attr("id", "personal_details_content").addClass("collapse");

$("#personal_details > legend")
    .attr("data-toggle", "collapse")
    .attr("data-target", "#personal_details_content")
    .attr("aria-expanded", "false").attr("aria-controls", "personal_details_content")
    .attr("data-parent", "#reserve_form");
```

I now can collapse my content but I also would like close the old element when openeing the new as in the bootstrap example.

What do I miss?

I created a [JsFiddle for the troubleshooting](http://jsfiddle.net/check24_7in/kvaau0hy/1/)

I highly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just fixed your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7qnghmzv/).
The adjustment was to add

```
class="panel"
```

to both `fieldsets`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that.
I will have to do that over jquery but thanks anyway.
Really appreciate it!